# xBee S6B (Wi-Fi) with Arduino - uploading data to Digi Device Cloud

Tags: upload, arduino, cloud, xbee

I am trying to use xBee S6B (Wi-Fi) with Arduino to upload data from my air quality sensor. So far, I've gotten my code to print out the results from the sensor, but I need to upload my data to the Device Cloud, to Data Stream. I've tried using SoftwareSerial, which works for inter-xBee communication (code attached below).

I discovered that in Data Streams in Device Cloud, there is a stream (Device ID)/serial/0, which is supposed to display the data from xBee. (from page 62 of xBee manual http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90002180_K.pdf)

Here's the code in Arduino I used to retrieve data from sensor and communicate (so far only with other xBee):

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define OK 0x00
#define BUSY 0x01
#define ERROR 0x80
#define SENSOR_INTERVAL 1000
SoftwareSerial xbee(8, 9); // RX, TX

void setup() {   // put your setup code here, to run once:
   Serial.begin(9600);
   xbee.begin(9600);  // communicate using SoftwareSerial (AT Mode)
   Wire.begin();

  Serial.println("Running...");
}


void loop() {
  Wire.requestFrom(0x5A,3);             // read 3 bytes from address of IAQ-engine
                                        // address of iAQ-engine is 0x5A
  uint16_t Intensity_value;
  uint8_t status;
  Intensity_value = Wire.read();  // read 1st byte
  Intensity_value <<= 8;          // shift bits for next byte
  Intensity_value |= Wire.read(); // read 2nd byte
  status = Wire.read();           // read status (3rd byte)


  switch (status) {
    case OK:
      // serial monitor
      Serial.print("Air Quality (CO2) : ");
      Serial.print(Intensity_value);
      Serial.println(" ppm");
      // xbee
      xbee.print("Air Quality (CO2) : ");
      xbee.print(Intensity_value);
      xbee.println(" ppm");
      break;
    case BUSY:

      Serial.println("The sensor is busy.");
      // xbee
      xbee.println("The sensor is busy.");
      break;
    case ERROR:
      Serial.println("Sensor ERROR.");

      xbee.println("Sensor ERROR.");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.print("Invalid status value : ");
      Serial.println(status);

      xbee.print("Invalid status value : ");
      xbee.println(status);
  }
  delay(SENSOR_INTERVAL);
}
```

Thanks for help!